# Convert CTE Query to Ordinary MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to convert `CTE` query to an ordinary MySQL query since I have issues implement it using CodeIgniter 3 Query Class with active record style to my code block.

Query with CTE

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT id,
                name,
                Max(build) AS build
         FROM   mytable
         WHERE  build <= 6
                AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
         GROUP  BY name) SELECT *
FROM   CTE
UNION
SELECT id,
       name,
       Min(build)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  name NOT IN (SELECT name
                    FROM   CTE)
       AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
GROUP  BY name
```

What I tried;

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT id,
               name,
               Max(build) AS build
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  build <= 6
               AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
        GROUP  BY name) AS cte
UNION
SELECT id,
       name,
       Min(build)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  name NOT IN (SELECT name
                    FROM   cte)
       AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
GROUP  BY name
```

When I try to run query above, it doesn't recognize table `cte` in `SELECT NAME FROM cte` part. Is there any way to fix this in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your table have rows with the same `id` but different `name` values?

Comment: Same `id`, same `name` can have multiple rows with different `build` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it would be more efficient to have only 2 queries those are used for `UNION`. Since the aggregation function `MIN` is used for the alternative `build` value selection, the `HAVING` clause can be used here.

Finally query can look like this

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       MAX(build) AS build
FROM   mytable
WHERE  build <= 6 AND id = /*id*/
GROUP  BY id, name
UNION
SELECT id,
       name,
       MIN(build) AS build
FROM   mytable t
WHERE id = /*id*/
      AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM mytable tt 
          WHERE tt.id = t.id AND t.build <= 6
      )
GROUP  BY id, name 
HAVING MIN(build) > 6
```

Comment: I see, thank you! In terms of performance it should also be better solution for heavy loops

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just duplicate the definition of `CTE`, and then simplify it. I think it comes down to:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       Max(build) AS build
FROM   mytable
WHERE  build <= 6
       AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
GROUP  BY name
UNION
SELECT id,
       name,
       Min(build)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  name NOT IN (SELECT name
           FROM   mytable
           WHERE  build <= 6
           AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
           )
       AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
GROUP  BY name
```

MySQL will figure out the most efficient query plan, so it hopefully does not need to query things twice.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try as

SELECT *
 FROM   (SELECT id,
           name,
           Max(build) AS build
    FROM   mytable
    WHERE  build <= 6
           AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
    GROUP  BY name) AS cte
UNION
   SELECT id,
   name,
   Min(build)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  name NOT IN (

    SELECT name,
           Max(build) AS build
    FROM   mytable
    WHERE  build <= 6
           AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
    GROUP  BY name
  )
   AND ` id ` = /*'id'*/
   GROUP  BY name
```